# Saying condolences if relative is hospitalised?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, politeness, offensive-language

Is it offensive to say 'condolences' to people with a relative who is hospitalised? Apparently there's this kind of assumption 'condolences' is sometimes reserved only to express sympathy/empathy re grief for actual death, so it's like some kind of jinx if I say to a potentially dying person. However, the assumption [appears to be false eg HIMYM S07E22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4asmV_imiuY).

Please explain answer and provide sources.

---

**Bounty note 1**: please give references/sources (i already said sources above though). Eg for things like this

> Because the word is so strongly associated with death, its use in a situation where a person might be going to die, could be taken as suggesting that the patient was as good as dead already. In such a situation it would be tactless, and potentially distressing, to say "Condolences". So, yes, it could be offensive to use the word when a relative has been hospitalised.

sounds like a personal opinion. sounds like a really good and well-founded opinion. but an opinion nevertheless

**Bounty note 2**: i'm a dumbass. the thing of davidlol from 2017 does say death only for UK. so davidlol are you arguing this: like in the UK definition of Cambridge it is death only?

Comment: Please provide your research, so we don't duplicate it. Please define "offensive". Please give more details about  the context. Please tell us what the intended function of the utterance is.

Comment: Hi @BCLC. I am not at all sure what form a source might take. As far as I know there is no official, authoritative list of when a word might be offensive. I have given a source for the word being most commonly used in relation to a death. I accept it is purely my personal opinion that using a death-related word about a hospital patient who is not yet dead could be distressing and so offensive. I hope somebody is able to give the answer you are looking for, but I do not see what authoritative source there could possibly be for something like this..

Comment: @davidlol adding that comment to answer may make your answer the 2nd best thing i guess

Comment: @BCLC Well, if nobody gives a better answer I will amend mine as you suggest. But lets hope you do get what you re looking for before your bounty expires.

Comment: Etiquette and manners vary geographically and according to social class, religious/ethnic group, how traditional/modern people are, and other factors; I'm not sure if there would be variation here, but it would be useful when looking for something authoritative enough to be cited as a source. Remarks from a religious leader might carry weight to some people, while Debrett's Modern Manners might be better than the Bible for a certain social group. (Example: "I'll pray for you" would be fitting for some people and offensive for others if a relative was in hospital.)

Comment: And just what would you consider a reference or source?

Comment: @Xanne not sure. something to credibly justify why people are offended when i say condolences when they have relatives in hospitals

Comment: Are we talking about using the word "condolences", or the more general notion of expressing sympathy? In the latter case, this wouldp probably be more appropriate for [interpersonal.se].

Comment: @Barmar using the word

Comment: It's instructive that none of the sites I've looked at with lists of suggestions for the wording in this illness situation use this word.

Comment: @BCLC Wait... so you're looking to ELU to give you a reference to justify that people you say 'My condolences' to for someone in the hospital -shouldn't be upset? Your reference is right there. Those people are upset at you. That's what the implication of the word is. Stop using it in those instances.

Comment: @Mitch begging the question much? what is their basis?

Comment: Oh, just wish them a "speedy recovery" and stop being so stubborn about this.

Comment: @ghurley clever i think i'll do both. wish condolences and show them this stackexchange post and also say i wish recovery. thanks!

Comment: @BCLC You have the mistaken assumption that dictionaries tell people what words are supposed to mean. Instead they are attempts at the meanings that most people have. It's nice when they capture -all- the nuances. 'Condolences' in health situations if not outright meaning, implies (to most people whether the dictionary says it or not) that someone has died. If they're not dead yet, then you're implying much worse news than there already is. That will make people feel pretty bad. People have given some references that support this if that's what makes you feel more confident in answers.

Comment: @Mitch, **(1)** it may be debatable whether *condolences* **as a matter of logic** implies death, but **(2)** even if it doesn't, it seems obvious that it is 'strongly associated with death' (as davidlol's answer puts it), which **as a matter of good manners** makes it a bad idea to use it when somebody is seriously ill. The OP and the other contributors to this page are at cross purposes, because the OP seems to be keen on 'litigating' (1), while most of the others are focused on (2), which disposes of the issue for most practical purposes, regardless of what the resolution of (1) is.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, totally agreed.

Comment: That might well be offensive and why are you Asking? If you doubt whether a word or phrase is suitable, don't use it. If the situation is clearly sensitive, as here, doubly don't use that word or phrase.

Remembering that "Saying condolences if relative is hospitalised?" doesn't become a Question just because it's given a question mark, have you considered taking the same query to English Language Learners?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin i'm a monolinguist trying to defend my honour against non-monolinguists. anyway i believe this will be resolved with davidlol's answer as soon as davidlol confirms the point with the UK cambridge thing

Comment: Telling a relative whose loved one is seriously ill in hospital "my condolences" is **insensitive**, save it for when the person dies. In situations where you want to express sympathy, you'd say "I'm so sorry to hear about your gran's fall. Let's hope for the best, we must trust that the doctors are doing everything they can OR (in a religious family) Let's pray for a miracle. It is in God's hands now etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Condolences can be expressed for any misfortune, but is most commonly used for the death of a relative, friend, neighbour, colleague etc.

Merriam-Webster gives several examples of [condolences](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condolence) being used following a death, but also gives this example:

> Within mere hours of Ted Lambros's rejection for tenure at Harvard, communications began to pour in from every important university center of the United States. Some were simply to express condolences.

Here, people  are expressing sympathy that Mr Lambros did not get the position he wanted.

The Cambridge dictionary [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condolence) is

> sympathy and sadness for the family or close friends of a person who has recently died, or an expression of this, especially in written form:

and this reflects the most common use of the term.

Nevertheless. it would be generally understood as a slightly humorous, but genuine, expression of sympathy for any minor misfortune such as a missed bus, broken saucer, unwanted sports result etc. It would also be understood as sympathy for a more serious, but non-deadly, misfortune.

However, in the case of a relative going into hospital, in a potentially life-threatening situation, it would not be appropriate. Because the word is so strongly associated with death, its use in a situation where a person might be going to die, could be taken as suggesting that the patient was as good as dead already. In such a situation it would be tactless, and potentially distressing, to say "Condolences". So, yes, it could be offensive to use the word when a relative has been hospitalised.

As far as I know there is no autoritative source as to what may cause distress to another person. We have a source for condolences being most commonly used after a death. In the case of a relativebeing hospitalised, each person must decide whether, in particular circumstances, it could cause distress to use a word associated with death. Similarly, one might feel it would be inappropriate to discuss what one planned to wear to the funeral, or speculate about the wake.

Comment: Thanks, davidlol! What is your source for the last paragraph, please?

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4asmV_imiuY

Comment: As I said,, it can be used humorously. How I Met Your Mother is intended to be funny. If someone has just told you that his relative has been hospitalised then cracking a joke might be seen as even less appropriate than offering condolences. Condolences is most commonly, but not exclusively, used after a death. Whether using it for a hospitalisation will offend depends on the relationship you have and many personal factors. You may choose to avoid saying something that might cause distress, but no authority can stop you.

Comment: 'as to what may cause distress to another person' --> but what is their right to be distressed? if someone calls me 'smart' in another language i'm only a little familiar with and i interpret this word to mean 'dumb' because of my poor understanding of the language, then do i have the right to be distressed/offended?

Comment: question re your Cambridge: the UK version says death but the US version allows non-death? 'an expression of sympathy esp. for the family of a person who has recently died, or the sympathy expressed:' see the 'esp' but UK version says this only

Comment: Edit: i'm a dumbass. the thing of davidlol from 2017 does say death only for UK. so are you arguing this: like in the UK definition of Cambridge it is death only?

Comment: anyhoo i'll just award bounty for you re the cambridge thing which i missed last time. but again UK definition Cambridge is what you're arguing?

Comment: if you say yes, then i'll accept answer.

Comment: @BCLC Thankyou.  Yes.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, we usually reserve condolences for the death of a relative. I think this is because suffering over the death is something that happens to the surviving relatives, so they deserve sympathy.

But when a relative is sick, we consider that it's the sick person who is suffering the most, and they're the ones we should express sympathy to. We send them "get well" cards. Even if another family member has to care for the sick relative, this is generally viewed as a family duty, not a form of suffering on their part.

I've never experienced caring for a loved one with dementia due to Alzheimer's Disease, but I've heard that it can be especially grueling. In some ways it's like you've already lost them -- the physical body is still there, but the "person" you had the relationship with is effectively gone. But even though you may express sincere sympathy for what they're going through, using the word "condolences" might still be seen as insensitive; the care they're giving to the person implies that they consider them alive.

Comment: source? reference?

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4asmV_imiuY

Comment: @BCLC That's a sitcom character using it as a form of hyperbole.

Comment: Reference: 60 years of life experience.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it offensive to say 'condolences' to people with a relative who is hospitalised?

No. It is simply not idiomatic, nor is it entirely appropriate.

The OED gives

> **condolence**
>
> **2.a. Outward expression of sympathy with the *grief* of others;**
>
> **Etymology:** < Latin condolēre = to condole v.,

And if we move to **condole**:

> 2.a. To *grieve* with; to *express sympathy with* another in his affliction. (The only extant use.)

Your question is about giving one's condolences to people with a relative who is hospitalised. However, people with a relative who is hospitalised are not grieving or suffering, nor are they afflicted with something awful.

It will be your experience that people with a relative who is hospitalised are generally worried, concerned, looking for some hope or good news.

Thus to offer condolences is not offensive, but inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. condolences is expressed **only** when a person is dead. You should not express "condolences" to the person who is is alive or any relative.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/condolence

Comment: Do you have any citations for this?

Comment: @JBrunoDSouza what's your citation please?

Comment: J Bruno DSouza, I wasn't notified of edit. The link says sorrow, misfortune *or* grief not *and* grief. Therefore, you misinterpreted?

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4asmV_imiuY